# Keras shared layer with different input sizes

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

As per the [shared layers documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#shared-layers) in Keras, one can create a shared layer and instantiate it with different input shapes. It gives an example of a `Conv2D` shared layer, as such:

```
a = Input(shape=(32, 32, 3))
b = Input(shape=(64, 64, 3))

conv = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), padding='same')
conved_a = conv(a)

# Only one input so far, the following will work:
assert conv.input_shape == (None, 32, 32, 3)

conved_b = conv(b)
# now the `.input_shape` property wouldn't work, but this does:
assert conv.get_input_shape_at(0) == (None, 32, 32, 3)
assert conv.get_input_shape_at(1) == (None, 64, 64, 3)
```

I am trying the same thing with a `Dense` layer but it seems to be not working. Here is what I have tried, but it seems to be erroring because of mismatch in the input shapes. Am I missing something?

```
tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
dense = Dense(100)
i1 = Input(shape=(10,))
i2 = Input(shape=(200,))
d1 = dense(i1)
d2 = dense(i1)
d3 = dense(i2)
```

Following is the stack trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-d3fc6212c6ef> in <module>()
      5 d1 = dense(i1)
      6 d2 = dense(i1)
----> 7 d3 = dense(i2)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    751       # Check input assumptions set after layer building, e.g. input shape.
    752       if build_graph or in_deferred_mode:
--> 753         self._assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
    754 
    755       if not in_deferred_mode:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in _assert_input_compatibility(self, inputs)
   1511                   ' incompatible with the layer: expected axis ' + str(axis) +
   1512                   ' of input shape to have value ' + str(value) +
-> 1513                   ' but received input with shape ' + str(shape))
   1514       # Check shape.
   1515       if spec.shape is not None:

ValueError: Input 0 of layer dense is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 10 but received input with shape [None, 200]
```

Comment: Your input data shape `[None, 200]` does not match `i1`, which except `[None, 10]`.

Comment: I see that. But the example provided by Keras does the similar thing with Conv2D layer and it works.

Comment: Why would you have a shared dense layer with different input_shapes. In conv layers it makes sense, in your case it doesn´t seem like it makes sense. (which is why dense layers are capable to do that)

Comment: @Digital-Thinking Trying to implement this paper - https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.05394 which trains an autoencoder with tied weights. I read some where the way to achieve tied weights in Keras is to use shared layer.

Comment: OK but does it has to have different input shapes? As far as I understood tie weights are just transposed shared layers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you apply the `dense` layer on the `i1` in this line:

```
d1 = dense(i1)
```

the weights of this Dense layer would be constructed and therefore in the future it would expect inputs with a compatible shape with its weights. That's why you see the following error after applying the `dense` layer on the `i2`:

```
expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 10
```

The shape of `i1` was `(10,)` and therefore the `dense` layer would expect samples of shape `(10,)`. But `i2` has a shape of `(200,)` and therefore is incompatible as the input of the `dense` layer.

The reason that the convolution layers could be applied on inputs with different width and height (but with the same number of channels) is simply because the shape of their weights (i.e. convolution kernel or filter) does not depend on the spatial dimension of the inputs (however, it depends on the number of channels in the input and that's why in the example you provided both `a` and `b` have 3 channels).